# How to get to elements of the page?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

This is weird and I feel sort-of-stupid.

In CRM, I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and checked that the yellow warning section is a DIV with id *Notifications* (and sub-DIVs called *Notification0*, *Notification1* etc.).

However, when I went `document.getElementById("Notifications")`, I got squat. WTF?!

Also, when I went `document.write("")`, nothing changed. In Cr and FF, it did but IE didn't react. Am I insane?

EDIT:

[image]

The above is a typo. When I try to execute:

```
document.getElementById("crmNotifications")
```

I get nada, neither... Suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Konrad for me works very well! You are in a normal form? Which entity? CRM Rollup? It's very strange.

Comment: RU12, on-line, **any** entity. Strange indeed.

Comment: @Pedro Azevedo - nothing strange really, this is because Konrad is running scripts from Console. I have provided more details in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not insane, and nothing wrong with CRM and browser too :)

If you are running javascript from the Console of the browser, you are in context of `window` of the whole page. However CRM forms content is lied inside `contentIFrame` iframe. IFrames actually are separate pages, you can even edit link to which this iframe points in F12 developer tools to any other link you want. Try to change `src` attribute in it to `http://www.bing.com` and you will see Bing home page inside CRM window (only ribbon will remain):

```
<iframe title="This is IFrame" id="contentIFrame" src="http://www.bing.com" 
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-top-style: none; 
               border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; 
               border-left-style: none; display: inline;" >
```

That's why you cannot get `crmNotifications` DOM element - because when running javascript from Console you are in context of parent window. When you specify `window.frames[0]` it will give you the first IFrame on the page (actually this is only one there), inside it you will be able to get `crmNotifications`, because it is there.

When you are running custom scripts which you have added via CRM customization - they are linked to the inner form page (to which IFrame points), that's why from those scripts you can get `crmNotifications` directly, because you are already on 'content' page context.

Comment: Hi @SergeyS thanks for your explanation is very useful but i execute the same command of Konrad and i get the div element. The behavior you mention is only for UR12?

Comment: No, this is not only for UR12. On which page did you try this? Some pages in CRM do not contain inner IFrames. And btw what browser is?

Comment: +1 for a great answer. However, I do recall that I used to do that the way @PedroAzevedo describes and it worked **then**. Perhaps there was a setting that hid the true problem from me...

Answer (score 3):

You aren't insane perhaps a little :D if i see well Notifications is the class not the id. The id is crmNotifications.
I write notifications and i have this [link](http://rockstarbits.blogspot.pt/2011/08/crm-2011-notification-area.html) in my bookmarks.

Comment: Sorry, typo there. I meant *crmNotifications*. I don't get the element anyway. See my edit, please. +1 for inanity. :)

Comment: You mean you can do that without *frames*, like @glosrob shows?! In IE **and** FF? What the duck?! (Typo intended.)

Comment: If you are in context of inner IFrame, you can do it directly. Please take a look at my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
frames[0].document.getElementById('crmNotifications')
```

For whatever reason in IE you need the `frames[0]` bit. It is the same if you want to use the `Xrm` object too.

Comment: Ah, I forgot all about it. Nevertheless - check your browsers. I get **exactly** the same (miss)behavior in FF too. I need to use *frames*. Do I recall wrongly or has it changed?! And when...? +1, of course.

Comment: Nothing was changed really, difference in that from where you are running javascripts (context matters).